# Dot products in SVM

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I was watching a lecture on Support Vector Machine by Patrick Winston and here he does this thing

[image]

Where he projects the distance vector $x_+$ $-$ $x_-$ (in red) on the unit vector (in blue) and tell that this is the width between the 2 hyperplanes (in white). That is, he performs $dot$ $product$ on  $x_+$ $-$ $x_-$ (in red) and an unit vector perpendicular to the hyperplane to find out the distance between the lines. (The equation is written at the right). How is this thing working? Can anyone please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to see this. Here is one:

Adding to $x_-$ anything parallel to the hyperplane -- that is orthogonal to $w$ -- does not change the dot product. We can use this to move $x_-$ to the projection of $x_+$ to the hyperplane through $x_-$, which we will call $x_{p}$. Then $x_+- x_{p}$ is parallel to $w$, and $(x_{p}-x_-)\cdot w=0$.

Now the distance between the hyperplanes is $|x_+- x_{p}|=(x_+- x_{p})\cdot \frac{w}{|w|}$, which is the same as $(x_+- x_-)\cdot \frac{w}{|w|}$ -- their difference being $(x_{p}-x_-)\cdot \frac{w}{|w|}=0$. This is what we wanted.